# HTML & CSS: Turn fonts and images into data strings

Tags: html, css, assets, content-encoding

How can I convert fonts and images (assets in general) to data attributes?

Would assets load faster or slower this way?

Comment: Are you talking of [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) or do you mean [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be aware that DataURI's are not supported by IE earlier than IE8. Also, IE8 has a limitation for at most 32KB of dataURI's in css assets. A more detailed description about DataURI's can be found at [this blog post](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/07/06/data-uris-make-css-sprites-obsolete/).

If you need the java implementation, you can find one [here](https://github.com/alexo/wro4j/blob/960f30a7fc30bf6e38946bf0afe136fd7ecd70de/wro4j-core/src/main/java/ro/isdc/wro/model/resource/processor/impl/css/CssDataUriPreProcessor.java):

This allow you to transform all images into a base64 encoded uri in css files. For more details about how to integrate this implementation into your project, visit [this page](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/Base64DataUriSupport):

Disclosure: I'm affiliated to wro4j project.

Answer (score 1):

Your pages would load slower because the data has to be downloaded with each request while a separate file can be cached. Try to keep usage of data uri's for small files only.

uri encoder for images: http://www.scalora.org/projects/uriencoder/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/)'s `readAsDataURL` meathod. But it only works in chrome for now.